# Best way to extract text from a Word doc without using COM/automation?

Tags: python, ms-word

Is there a reasonable way to extract plain text from a Word file that doesn't depend on COM automation?  (This is a a feature for a web app deployed on a non-Windows platform - that's non-negotiable in this case.)

Antiword seems like it might be a reasonable option, but it seems like it might be abandoned.

A Python solution would be ideal, but doesn't appear to be available.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use catdoc or antiword for this, whatever gives the result that is the easiest to parse. I have embedded this in python functions, so it is easy to use from the parsing system (which is written in python).

```
import os

def doc_to_text_catdoc(filename):
    (fi, fo, fe) = os.popen3('catdoc -w "%s"' % filename)
    fi.close()
    retval = fo.read()
    erroroutput = fe.read()
    fo.close()
    fe.close()
    if not erroroutput:
        return retval
    else:
        raise OSError("Executing the command caused an error: %s" % erroroutput)

# similar doc_to_text_antiword()
```

The -w switch to catdoc turns off line wrapping, BTW.

Comment: Note that python 3 removes popen3, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3

Comment: Worth noting that antiword doesn't work on the most recent docx formats. Their website states they support "Word 2, 6, 7, 97, 2000, 2002 and 2003"

Answer (score 21):

(Same answer as [extracting text from MS word files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125222/extracting-text-from-ms-word-files-in-python))

Use the native Python docx module which I made this week. Here's how to extract all the text from a doc:

```
document = opendocx('Hello world.docx')

# This location is where most document content lives 
docbody = document.xpath('/w:document/w:body', namespaces=wordnamespaces)[0]

# Extract all text
print getdocumenttext(document)
```

See [Python DocX site](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

100% Python, no COM, no .net, no Java, no parsing serialized XML with regexs.

Comment: Thank you very much for creating this library. I know you've posted this 3 years ago, but is there any way to sort of convert a DOCX document to HTML using your library? Cheers

Comment: @mikemaccana can it parse .doc(not .docx) files also?

Comment: Please ask about .doc files as separate question.

Answer (score 4):

If all you want to do is extracting text from Word files (.docx), it's possible to do it only with Python. Like Guy Starbuck wrote it, you just need to unzip the file and then parse the XML. Inspired by `python-docx`, I have written a [simple function](http://etienned.github.io/posts/extract-text-from-word-docx-simply/) to do this:

```
try:
    from xml.etree.cElementTree import XML
except ImportError:
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML
import zipfile


"""
Module that extract text from MS XML Word document (.docx).
(Inspired by python-docx <https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx>)
"""

WORD_NAMESPACE = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}'
PARA = WORD_NAMESPACE + 'p'
TEXT = WORD_NAMESPACE + 't'


def get_docx_text(path):
    """
    Take the path of a docx file as argument, return the text in unicode.
    """
    document = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
    xml_content = document.read('word/document.xml')
    document.close()
    tree = XML(xml_content)

    paragraphs = []
    for paragraph in tree.getiterator(PARA):
        texts = [node.text
                 for node in paragraph.getiterator(TEXT)
                 if node.text]
        if texts:
            paragraphs.append(''.join(texts))

    return '\n\n'.join(paragraphs)
```

Comment: Great piece of code! A small remark about your blog, if the background of the code was not black, that would be more readable.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the comment. The problem is that I 'hacked' a bit the Github CSS so the colors match my site. But when Github make changes to their CSS, I have to patch my stylesheet again, like right now. Not sure I'll keep this approach...

Answer (score 3):

Using the OpenOffice API, and Python, and [Andrew Pitonyak's excellent online macro book](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) I managed to do this. Section 7.16.4 is the place to start.

One other tip to make it work without needing the screen at all is to use the Hidden property:

```
RO = PropertyValue('ReadOnly', 0, True, 0)
Hidden = PropertyValue('Hidden', 0, True, 0)
xDoc = desktop.loadComponentFromURL( docpath,"_blank", 0, (RO, Hidden,) )
```

Otherwise the document flicks up on the screen (probably on the webserver console) when you open it.

Answer (score 2):

**tika-python**

A Python port of the Apache Tika library, According to the documentation Apache tika supports text extraction from over 1500 file formats.

**Note:** It also works charmingly with **pyinstaller**

Install with pip :

```
pip install tika
```

**Sample:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from tika import parser
parsed = parser.from_file('/path/to/file')
print(parsed["metadata"]) #To get the meta data of the file
print(parsed["content"]) # To get the content of the file
```

Link to official [GitHub](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python)

Comment: I tried your example and it seems it tries to download and start a Java `.jar` file: " Retrieving http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/tika/tika-server/1.18/tika-server-1.18.jar" <-- but then it fails with HTTP 403.

Comment: Follow these steps  
1. You can manually download tika from [here](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/tika/tika-server-1.18.jar)  

2. Then open tika.py from \Lib\site-packages\tika folder and replace TikaJarPath = os.getenv('TIKA_PATH', "path\to\tika-server.jar\folder")

`TikaJarPath = os.getenv('TIKA_PATH', "F:\Projects\python\tika")`

Answer (score 1):

Open Office has an [API](http://api.openoffice.org/)

Answer (score 1):

For docx files, check out the Python script docx2txt available at

http://cobweb.ecn.purdue.edu/~kak/distMisc/docx2txt

for extracting the plain text from a docx document.

Answer (score 1):

[This worked well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516044/is-it-possible-to-read-word-files-doc-docx-in-python/30122239#30122239) for .doc and .odt.

It calls openoffice on the command line to convert your file to text, which you can then simply load into python.

(It seems to have other format options, though they are not apparenlty documented.)

Comment: openoffice and libreoffice are quite bad for deal with MS formats.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly **don't use "pip install tika**", this has been developed for mono-user (one developper working on his laptop) and not for multi-users (multi-developpers).

The small class TikaWrapper.py bellow which uses Tika in command line is widely enough to meet our needs.

You just have to instanciate this class with JAVA_HOME path and the Tika jar path, that's all ! And it works perfectly for lot of formats (e.g: PDF, DOCX, ODT, XLSX, PPT, etc.).

```
#!/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Class to extract metadata and text from different file types (such as PPT, XLS, and PDF)
# Developed by Philippe ROSSIGNOL
#####################
# TikaWrapper class #
#####################
class TikaWrapper:

    java_home = None
    tikalib_path = None

    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, java_home, tikalib_path):
        self.java_home = java_home
        self.tika_lib_path = tikalib_path

    def extractMetadata(self, filePath, encoding="UTF-8", returnTuple=False):
        '''
        - Description:
          Extract metadata from a document
        
        - Params:
          filePath: The document file path
          encoding: The encoding (default = "UTF-8")
          returnTuple: If True return a tuple which contains both the output and the error (default = False)
        
        - Examples:
          metadata = extractMetadata(filePath="MyDocument.docx")
          metadata, error = extractMetadata(filePath="MyDocument.docx", encoding="UTF-8", returnTuple=True)
        '''
        cmd = self._getCmd(self._cmdExtractMetadata, filePath, encoding)
        out, err = self._execute(cmd, encoding)
        if (returnTuple): return out, err
        return out

    def extractText(self, filePath, encoding="UTF-8", returnTuple=False):
        '''
        - Description:
          Extract text from a document
        
        - Params:
          filePath: The document file path
          encoding: The encoding (default = "UTF-8")
          returnTuple: If True return a tuple which contains both the output and the error (default = False)
        
        - Examples:
          text = extractText(filePath="MyDocument.docx")
          text, error = extractText(filePath="MyDocument.docx", encoding="UTF-8", returnTuple=True)
        '''
        cmd = self._getCmd(self._cmdExtractText, filePath, encoding)
        out, err = self._execute(cmd, encoding)
        return out, err

    # ===========
    # = PRIVATE =
    # ===========

    _cmdExtractMetadata = "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -jar ${TIKALIB_PATH} --metadata ${FILE_PATH}"
    _cmdExtractText = "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -jar ${TIKALIB_PATH} --encoding=${ENCODING} --text ${FILE_PATH}"

    def _getCmd(self, cmdModel, filePath, encoding):
        cmd = cmdModel.replace("${JAVA_HOME}", self.java_home)
        cmd = cmd.replace("${TIKALIB_PATH}", self.tika_lib_path)
        cmd = cmd.replace("${ENCODING}", encoding)
        cmd = cmd.replace("${FILE_PATH}", filePath)
        return cmd

    def _execute(self, cmd, encoding):
        import subprocess
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out, err = process.communicate()
        out = out.decode(encoding=encoding)
        err = err.decode(encoding=encoding)
        return out, err
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone wants to do in Java language there is Apache poi api. extractor.getText() will extract plane text from docx . Here is the link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi_word/apache_poi_word_text_extraction.htm

Answer (score 0):

**Textract-Plus**

Use textract-plus which can extract text from most of the document extensions including doc , docm , dotx and docx.
(It uses antiword as a backend for doc files)
[refer docs](https://textract-plus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Install-

```
pip install textract-plus
```

Sample-

```
import textractplus as tp
text=tp.process('path/to/yourfile.doc')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) the swiss-army-knife of documents. It converts from every format to nearly every other format. From the demos page

```
pandoc -s input_file.docx -o output_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [Etienne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20663596/12875177).
With python 3.9 `getiterator` was deprecated in ET, so you need to replace it with `iter`:

```
def get_docx_text(path):
    """
    Take the path of a docx file as argument, return the text in unicode.
    """
    document = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
    xml_content = document.read('word/document.xml')
    document.close()
    tree = XML(xml_content)

    paragraphs = []
    for paragraph in tree.iter(PARA):
        texts = [node.text
                 for node in paragraph.iter(TEXT)
                 if node.text]
        if texts:
            paragraphs.append(''.join(texts))

    return '\n\n'.join(paragraphs)
```