# How to extract just plain text from .doc & .docx files?

Tags: unix, extract, docx, doc, text-extraction

Anyone know of anything they can recommend in order to extract just the plain text from a `.doc` or `.docx`?

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42482) - wondered if there were any other suggestions?

Comment: This is a perfect fit for Software Recommendations.  It should be transferred there.

Comment: If we have `Software Recommendations` why to do not transfer here? I also search software for similar tasks and do not found there best answer. But could recommend `pandoc` as best solution which even tables convert correctly. So I suggest reopen question.

Comment: You obviously aren't on a Mac, but if you were you could use 'textutil' at the command line to quickly get plain text from various proprietary document types.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/383134/should-how-to-extract-just-plain-text-from-doc-docx-files-be-migrated)

Comment: @Taryn: care to explain why this Q is off-topic but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252220/how-to-extract-plain-text-from-ms-word-document-file-in-pure-c is not?

Answer (score 80):

If you want the pure plain text(my requirement) then all you need is

```
unzip -p some.docx word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]]\{1,\}//g'
```

Which I found at [command line fu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4311/extract-plain-text-from-ms-word-docx-files)

It unzips the docx file and gets the actual document then strips all the xml tags. Obviously all formatting is lost.

Comment: I like this command, but often newlines are still useful data to have in the final version. Therefore I used the following command instead:  
  
`unzip -p document.docx word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<\/w:p>/\n/g; s/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]\n]\{1,\}//g'`  
  
Note the additional sed argument, replacing XML representations of newlines with the actual newline character, and I edited the last sed argument to not strip newline characters. This makes the above command far more useful for diff-ing Word documents.

Comment: Thanks Rob! @Jeff: I agree but the following command works better for me in practice: unzip -p document.docx word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<\/w:p>/ /g; s/<[^>]\{1,\}>/ /g; s/[^[:print:]]\{1,\}/ /g'

Comment: Very nice. Is it also possible to edit the XML data inside the Word document without corrupting it? And how?

Comment: How does this fare with non-ASCII characters? Especially the more esoteric character sets?

Comment: @einpoklum the first bit of the command gets the raw xml so that will work fine. the second bit gets all the none xml tag strings and separates them with a new line. So as long as the sed does not barf on esoteric character sets you should be fine. Please post a reply if you find that is not the case.

Comment: Good idea for recovering corrupted files.

Comment: this doesn't preserve newline

Comment: I agree with Jeff 
besides rob's suggestion does loose some text (close to recurring start of lines seem to be suppressed.

Comment: @jeff-mcjunkin nice snipet, thanks a lot! I think you should add `s/<w:br/>/\n/g;` too ;)

Answer (score 47):

### LibreOffice

One option is [libreoffice](http://www.libreoffice.org)/openoffice in headless mode (make sure all other instances of libreoffice are closed first):

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to "txt:Text (encoded):UTF8" mydocument.doc
```

For more details see e.g. this link: http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/2641/convert-to-command-line-parameter/

For a list of libreoffice filters see http://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core/tree/filter/source/config/fragments/filters

Since the openoffice command line syntax is a bit too complicated, there is a handy wrapper which can make the process easier: [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/).

### Apache POI

Another option is [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) — a well supported Java library which unlike antiword can read, create and convert `.doc`, `.docx`, `.xls`, `.xlsx`, `.ppt`, `.pptx` files.

Here is the simplest possible Java code for converting a `.doc` or `.docx` document to plain text:

```js
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.POITextExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.extractor.ExtractorFactory;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JException;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException;

public class WordToTextConverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            convertWordToText(args[0], args[1]);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aiobe) {
            System.out.println("Usage: java WordToTextConverter <word_file> <text_file>");
        }
    }

    public static void convertWordToText(String src, String desc) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(src);
            final POITextExtractor extractor = ExtractorFactory.createExtractor(fs);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(desc);
            fw.write(extractor.getText());
            fw.flush();
            fs.close();
            fw.close();

        } catch (IOException | OpenXML4JException | XmlException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


# Maven dependencies (pom.xml):

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>my.wordconv</groupId>
<artifactId>my.wordconv.converter</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

NOTE: You will need to add the apache poi libraries to the classpath. On ubuntu/debian the libraries can be installed with `sudo apt-get install libapache-poi-java` — this will install them under `/usr/share/java`. For other systems you'll need to [download](https://poi.apache.org/download.html) the library and unpack the archive to a folder that you should use instead of `/usr/share/java`. If you use maven/gradle (the recommended option), then include the [org.apache.poi dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi) as shown in the code snippet.

The same code will work for both `.doc` and `.docx` as the required converter implementation will be chosen by inspecting the binary stream.

Compile the class above (assuming it's in the default package, and the apache poi jars are under `/usr/share/java`):

```
javac -cp /usr/share/java/*:. WordToTextConverter.java
```

Run the conversion:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/*:. WordToTextConverter doc.docx doc.txt
```

A [clonable gradle project](https://bitbucket.org/ccpizz/poi-doc2text-converter-gradle/src) which pulls all necessary dependencies and generates the wrapper shell script (with `gradle installDist`).

Comment: If you're going to add Java options into the mix, I'd like to mention 'my' docx4j (which also handles pptx, xlsx).  For text extraction, you'd use  https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/TextUtils.java

Comment: See also question 1686 on Ask LibreOffice about running the command line conversion in parallel with a running LibreOffice instance: http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/1686/how-to-not-connect-to-a-running-instance/

Comment: When I tried using libreoffice to convert some docx files, I got this weird error `Error: Please reverify input parameters...`, which I disappeared when I switched to `--convert-to "txt:Text (encoded):UTF8"`, so I'd recommend that (even if you don't have non-ascii characters).

Comment: This is the ideal approach IMO. But to get it working in OSX, I had to uninstall the GUI-installed version, then run `brew install libreoffice`. Then, the command that worked was `soffice --headless ...` instead of `libreoffice --headless ...`. Although this question is closed, it's *the very first* google result, so it might be worth adding this to the answer to help us hapless searchers.

Comment: @senderle: no need to uninstall the existing GUI-installed version — in that scenario the binary is just not available in $PATH; you can still call it on macos e.g. with `/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --help`

Comment: @ccpizza true, but I like to cede as much control of my path to package managers as possible. With homebrew, it Just Works.

Comment: @senderle: fair enough; `brew cask info libreoffice` points to the formula at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/libreoffice.rb where you can see it additionally puts a wrapper script under `/usr/local/bin/soffice`. It's useful to know what exactly is going on just in case the formula gets removed, or in case you need a newer version than the one provided by brew.

Answer (score 16):

Try [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/). It supports most document formats (every MS Office format, OpenOffice/LibreOffice formats, PDF, etc.) using Java-based libraries (among others, [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)). It's very simple to use:

```
java -jar tika-app-1.4.jar --text ./my-document.doc
```

Answer (score 10):

## Try "antiword" or "antiword-xp-rb"

My favorite is antiword:

http://www.winfield.demon.nl/

And here's a similar project which claims support for docx:

https://github.com/rainey/antiword-xp-rb/wiki

Comment: The have used (the upper) antiword many times, but it does not works with docx. From its page: "Antiword converts the binary files from Word 2, 6, 7, 97, 2000, 2002 and 2003 to plain text and to PostScript"

Answer (score 5):

I find [wv](http://abisource.com/downloads/wv/) to be better than catdoc or antiword. It can deal with .docx and convert to text or html. Here is a function I added to my .bashrc to temporarily view the file in the terminal. Change it as required.

```
# open word in less (ie worl document.doc)
worl() {
    DOC=$(mktemp /tmp/output.XXXXXXXXXX)
    wvText $1 $DOC
    less $DOC
    rm $DOC
}
```

Comment: For those on OSX, you can `brew install wv && brew install elinks`.

Comment: Works a treat and supports .doc and .docx

Answer (score 1):

I recently dealt with this issue and found OpenOffice/LibreOffice commandline tools to be unreliable in production (thousands of docs processed, dozens concurrently).

Ultimately, I built a light-weight wrapper, [DocRipper](https://github.com/pzaich/doc_ripper) that is much faster and grabs all text from .doc, .docx and .pdf without formatting. DocRipper utilizes Antiword, grep and pdftotext to grab text and return it.