# Open Source library for Linux C++ to convert word document to plain text

Tags: c++, c, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to extract plain text from ms word document file in pure c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252220/how-to-extract-plain-text-from-ms-word-document-file-in-pure-c)

I am developing a c\c++ program to convert .doc file to formatted plain text under Linux.Is there any open source library to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: have you searched stackoverflow? I found these duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8252220/79455 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5671988/79455

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252220/how-to-extract-plain-text-from-ms-word-document-file-in-pure-c).

You could have a look at the open source C library used by Abiword, [wv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wvware/).

You can also call out to a batch convert tool

- Open source batch converter, based on OpenOffice:
  http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/
- The open source for unix:
  http://www.wagner.pp.ru/~vitus/software/catdoc/
- Proprietary for
  windows: http://doc2txt.com/. Note I haven't tried this one.