# git configuration file for diffing docx

Tags: git, bash

I wanted to be able to diff docx file and found that using the following code we are able to extract the text from docx files.
`unzip -p some.docx word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]]\{1,\}//g' | fold -w 80`

However, I am struggling to include this into the gitattribute file.
Can someone comment on how this line needs to be modified so that git uses the current file instead of the hardlink to the docx file

I have tried the following in git config but it causes an error:

`[diff "word"]
      textconv= unzip -p $LOCAL | sed -e 's/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]]\{1,\}//g' |`

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: sed seems like an awful hack for parsing docx's XML. I would look into getting a more robust utility for converting docx to plaintex. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671988/how-to-extract-just-plain-text-from-doc-docx-files-unix

Comment: Incorrect git configuration file. I suspect its the syntax of the command line code. – Thinker just now edit

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a proper solution](http://xcafebabe.blogspot.hu/2012/09/sexy-comparison-of-word-documents-with.html) for that, simply stripping the strings, that might cause you some headache.

Comment: Incorrect git configuration file. I suspect its the syntax of the command line code.