# command line to convert all .docx in a directory (and subdirectories) to text file and write new files

Tags: grep, unzip, doc

I would like to convert all .docx files in a directory (and subdirectories) to text files from the command line (so I can use grep after on these files). I found this

```
unzip -p tutu.docx word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<\/w:p>/\n/g; s/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]\n]\{1,\}//g'
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671988/how-to-extract-just-plain-text-from-doc-docx-files-unix) which works well but it sends the file in the terminal. I would like to write the new text file (.txt for instance) in the same directory as the .docx file. And I would like a script to do this recursively.

I have this, using antiword, that do what I want for .doc files but it doesn't work for .docx files.

```
find . -name '*.doc' | while read i; do antiword -i 1 "${i}" >"${i/doc/txt}"; done
```

I tried to mix both but without success... A command line that would do both at the same time would be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script..

- converts all docx files in the directory where you run it, recursively (adapt `.` in `find .` to your wished starting point)
- writes the txt files to where it found the `docx` file

Bash script:

```
find . -name "*.docx" | while read file; do
    unzip -p $file word/document.xml |
        sed -e 's/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]]\{1,\}//g' > "${file/docx/txt}"
done
```

Afterwards you can run the grep like this:

```
grep -r "some text" --include "*.txt" .
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like it is not working recursively though. And, instead of creating a new directory, i'd like it to write the file to the directory where it found the .docx file. Any adjustment?

Comment: @jejuba changed the script so it is starting at the current directory. It *does* work recursively (also the old version). Changed it so it stores the txt where it found the docx. Also the grep is a bit more complex now, as you need to do it recursively too

Comment: OK thanks it works well. The problem is that I have .docx files that are not truly .docx files. I have to sort this out. Many thanks.

Comment: @jejuba if you want then upload the docx file and link it here and I can help you with converting it to txt

Comment: Ok, I understand what went wrong. I kept having the following message: ambiguous redirect. The script would not go in a directory if there was a space in it. I added quotes around ... > "${file/docx/txt}" and now it's working fine! THanks

Comment: @jejuba thanks for the hint, I corrected the script above

Answer (score 5):

You can use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to convert docx files. It doesn't support `.doc` files so you will need both pandoc and antiword.

Reusing your `while` loop:

```
find . -name '*.docx' | while read i; do pandoc --from docx --to plain "${i}" >"${i/docx/txt}"; done
```

Comment: thank you. I tried using pandoc but for some reaons it creates empty .txt files with the following warning: pandoc: Unkown reader: docx. Any idea? But the loop is good: it is recursive and creates the file where it was.

Comment: docx support was added in the version [1.13](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/1.13). Which version do you use ? You may need to [install a recent version](http://pandoc.org/installing.html).

Comment: Right, I have version 1.12... It is the one available with the stable Debian version. I have to see if I can install it from testing. Best,