# Extract text content from docx and pptx that contains text & images - linux

Tags: python, linux, perl, text-extraction

**docx to txt:**

I tried the following code for extracting text from docx. It does not work when docx has images.

```
unzip -p some.docx word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]]\{1,\}//g'
```

For **pptx to txt**, I found a Perl script to extract txt. It does not work when the pptx has images - the same.

I want extracted txt content for enabling search option among documents. So a command/script that will skip the images and convert the docx text content to txt will even help!

Comment: Why is this tagged as `python`?

Comment: I would prefer linux command but even perl/python script will do.

Comment: If you have motivation, `strings some.docx` and sort it by hand but it will be long and painful

Comment: Why is sort needed? I want extracted text alone. Even skipping out the images is fine.

Comment: You have a great solution in your question. I've been looking for the exact parsing you have to extract the text from docx files (albeit without images.) Bravo.

Answer (score 4):

The SO question [How to extract just plain text from .doc & .docx files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671988/how-to-extract-just-plain-text-from-doc-docx-files-unix) provides other options.
The `libreoffice` answer almost works, probably did in 2012.
Now (LibreOffice 5.1) try:

```
libreoffice --convert-to txt text some.docx
```

or

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to txt text some.docx
```

Be sure that you do not have `libreoffice` already open.