# Can't print result of shell command inside script

Tags: shell

I found this helpful post on how to [extract the text from a DOCX file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25620447/9158985), and I wanted to make it into a little shell script. My attempt is as follows

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "pass in a docx file to get the text within"
    exit 1
fi

text="$(unzip -p $1 word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<\/w:p>/\n/g; s/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]\n]\{1,\}//g')"
echo $text
```

However, this does not print the result as expected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What result did you expect, and what result did you get?

Comment: You should run this through https://shellcheck.net first.

Comment: shellcheck.net figured it out. Needed to put quotes around $1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), I found that I needed to put quotes around the `$1`. The final script, as approved by shellcheck, is:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "pass in a docx file to get the text within"
    exit 1
fi

text=$(unzip -p "$1" word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<\/w:p>/\n/g; s/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]\n]\{1,\}//g')
echo "$text"
```

Comment: Good job solving the issue. Both command and process substitution are subshells. They are there own separate environment. As such, you must quote within them just the same as you would quote any command on the command line.