# python: find numbers in docx file and replace

Tags: python, python-docx

I want to read the docx file in python.
then extract numbers from that
like:

```
with open('test.docx') as t:
    text = t.readlines()
a = []
a.append([int(s) for s in text.split() if s.isdigit()])
a = [int(numeric_string) for numeric_string in a]
```

Thanks for any bits of help

Comment: ...and what is wrong with your current script?

Comment: @Tim I don't think reading a docx file (zipped XML) this way will work ;) but OP should make it clear.

Comment: You could convert it to a text file first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671988/how-to-extract-just-plain-text-from-doc-docx-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [docx](https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/) library to read the content of .docx files.

```
pip install python-docx
```

Adapting some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228106/how-to-extract-text-from-an-existing-docx-file-using-python-docx) and combining with the code you posted I got:

```
import docx

def getText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)

text = getText('Doc1.docx')

a = [int(s) for s in text.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

which worked for me with a simple test file - although you may need to adjust some parts depending on how you want the search for numbers to work.