# Is it possible to read Word files (.doc/.docx) in Python

Tags: python, ms-word

I want to create a validation tool;

Can any one help me read .doc/.docx documents in Python in order to search and compare the file contents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [extracting text from MS word files in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125222/extracting-text-from-ms-word-files-in-python)

Answer (score 8):

Yes it is possible. LibreOffice (at least) has a command line option to convert files that works a treat. Use that to convert the file to text. Then load the text file into Python as per routine manoeuvres.

This worked for me on LibreOffice 4.2 / Linux:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to txt:Text /path_to/document_to_convert.doc
```

I've tried a few methods (including odt2txt, antiword, zipfile, lpod, uno). The above soffice command was the first that worked simply and without error. [This question](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/14130/how-do-i-install-filters-for-the-soffice-command/) on using filters with `soffice` on [ask.libreoffice.org](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/14130) helped me.

Comment: You might also want to use the '--outdir' parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using PyWin32 to access Word via COM, although that will be a little ugly. You could also look at IronPython since it's built with .NET and may have better hooks into Office.

See also the following:

- [Reading/Writing MS Word files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188444/reading-writing-ms-word-files-in-python)
- https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/16/python-and-microsoft-office-using-pywin32/
- http://www.galalaly.me/index.php/2011/09/use-python-to-parse-microsoft-word-documents-using-pywin32-library/