# Python EasyGUI Word Count

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a word counter program incorporating **easygui** for **file selection**. I currently use Eclipse SDK with PyDev plugin (If there's any recommendations for a better Python environment).

Here is my code in its current state:

```
#This program is supposed to take a word file, and count the amount of lines and
#words. If the entered file is not a .txt, .doc, or .docx, then the program will
#ask for a different file.

from easygui import fileopenbox

filename = fileopenbox()
lines, words = 0, 0

#This method will count the amount of lines and words in a program and display
#it to the user
def word_count():
    if filename.endswith('.docx'): #If the file extension is .docx
        print("Your file has" + num_words + "words") #Print the amount of lines and words in the file.
    elif filename.endswith('.doc'): #If the file extension is .doc
        #<CODE WHICH COUNTS LINES AND WORDS>
        print("Your file has", lines, "lines, and" ,"words") #Print the amount of lines and words in the file.
    elif filename.endswith('.txt'): #If the file extension is .txt
        #<CODE WHICH COUNTS LINES AND WORDS>
        print("Your file has", lines, "lines, and" ,"words") #Print the amount of lines and words in the file.
    elif filename.endswith('.py'): #If the file extension is .py
        #<CODE WHICH COUNTS LINES AND WORDS>
        print("Your file has", lines, "lines, and" ,"words") #Print the amount of lines and words in the file.
    elif filename.endswith('.java'): #If the file extension is .java
        #<CODE WHICH COUNTS LINES AND WORDS>
        print("Your file has", lines, "lines, and" ,"words") #Print the amount of lines and words in the file.
    else:
        print("Are you trying to annoy me? How about giving me a TEXT or SOURCE CODE file, genius?")#Print an insulting error message.
```

As the code shows, I want the program to read the file extension, and if it matches any of those, run the word count code. However, my question is, what is that word count code? it seems like the use of fileopenbox() from easygui will make things even more complicated. any helps are appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: You should post the code in the question itself.

Comment: Could you post the code as *text*?

Comment: Its hard to post it as text while keeping the formatting in tact :/

Comment: @DavonG It wasn’t that hard compared to typing the text off the screenshot :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from easygui import fileopenbox

def word_count(filename):
    if not filename.endswith(('.txt', '.py', '.java')):
        print('Are you trying to annoy me? How about giving me a TEXT or SOURCE CODE file, genius?')
        return

    with open(filename) as f:
        n_lines = 0
        n_words = 0
        for line in f:
            n_lines += 1
            n_words += len(line.split())
    print('Your file has {} lines, and {} words'.format(n_lines, n_words))

filename = fileopenbox()
word_count(filename)
```

Comment: Really appreciate the answer falsetru. It compiles perfectly, but when I run and select the file, I recieve this: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vonologic\workspace\Word Counter\main.py", line 23, in <module>
    word_count(filename)
TypeError: word_count() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: Actually, the OP wants to know "what is that word count code". Your answer shows how it might be done for plain text files, but does so unconditionally, not even differentiating with `if/elf`s on the extension like the OP's did. Sorry, no cigar.

Comment: @DavonG, pass filename to word_count: `word_count(filename)`.

Comment: @DavonG: The code in this answer is probably OK for the last three file extensions because they're plain text. For MS-Word documents you're going to need a tool that can parse the file format. There are many questions here on SO about doing that. Take a [look](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+read+word+doc).

Comment: @falsetru: You probably don't want `'rb'` for plain text. In fact on Windows you might need to specify `'rt'`. The UnicodeDecodeError is probably because the OP tried it with a non-plain text file.

Comment: @martineau, Thank you for your advice. I excluded .docx, .doc, and revert 'rb' mode to 'r'.

Comment: @DavonG: The answer to [Is it possible to read Word files (.doc/.docx) in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516044/is-it-possible-to-read-word-files-doc-docx-in-python) looks like a good reference.

Comment: @falsetru Also "wc += len(line.split())" wc was never declared before that, and I'm getting an error because of it. I set it to 0, but I got a UnicodeDecodeError afterwards.

Comment: @DavonG, Oops, I fixed that.  Try run the script in console (not in pydev).  If UnicodeDecodeError still exist, please change `open(filename)` to `open(filename, 'rb')`, and retry.

Comment: @DavonG, No, not in IDLE. In `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @falsetru I'm supposed to just write the code in the command prompt? Without indentations and formatting...?

Comment: @DavonG, Save your script as `wc.py` or some other name you like. Then open cmd.exe, run the script: `python wc.py`.

Comment: Where should I place it? CMD can't seem to find the script

Comment: I get UnicodeDecodeErrors with and without the RB. Just for confirmation, did I do this right? http://i.imgur.com/rxRmYdD.png

Comment: Update: Never mind, it works perfectly. I was using a text file with a bunch of weird characters, which is why it didn't work before.