# reading docx with python2.7

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a docx file with file with the following code:

```
from docx import Document
doc = Document('test.docx')
```

But when I try to print it, i get this:

```
<docx.api.Document object at 0x02952C70>
```

How can I read the content inside the file?

I read that docx changed recently so, the old questions/answers don't apply anymore.

Comment: Did you try accessing the paragraphs?

Comment: No, how can I do this @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams ?

Comment: Did you try doing what it tells you to in the docs?

Comment: Yes, I already checked the docs, but I didn't see a function about paragraphs. I just saw the sections function whci also returns a similar hexadecimal code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to not use the `docx` module to extract information from Word files using Python. [One solution, (there are many), from etienne](http://etienned.github.io/posts/extract-text-from-word-docx-simply/) is a very basic version of `docx` which may remove the hexadecimal numbers that you are getting. However, like SebasSBM's answer, it won't work for other features, such as tables etc.

If that still doesn't work, I would suggest looking at [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42482/best-way-to-extract-text-from-a-word-doc-without-using-com-automation); maybe one of them will still be relevant to your new docx format.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the structure of the Document object here:

[Source code for docx.api](http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/docx/api.html)

For example, if you want to get the property "paragraphs":

```
doc = Document('test.docx')
paragraphs = doc.paragraphs()
```

I hope this will help.

EDIT: I have found this snippet in the [python-docx's gitHub repository](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/72) and edited it a little here:

```
document = docx.Document(filename)
docText = '\n\n'.join([
    paragraph.text.encode('utf-8') for paragraph in document.paragraphs
])
print docText
```

The join() function receives a list of strings encoded in UTF-8 from the paragraphs in the array returned by paragraphs property. So the result would look like:

```
paragraph 1

paragraph 2

paragraph 3
```

It looks like this works, but it doesn't print tables, headers or footers.

EDIT: This link is the main index for all documentation about python-docx:

[python-docx 0.7.4 documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Ok, but I'm still getting hexadecimal codes, and not pure text

Comment: I've edited the answer apporting new information and a code snippet. Check it out.

Comment: thanks, but I'm getting problems with special characters  (e.g. instead of getting são, I'm getting s├úo).

Comment: Maybe, in your case, you don't need to encode - so it would be just paragraph.text without the encode() method, or you need to encode it using the encoding that your software uses - please forgive the repetition.