# python module to convert doc/pdf/docx/rtf formats to text

Tags: python, pdf, text, module, doc

I am searching google for answers but i could not get one module to convert doc/pdf/docx/rtf to text

Is there any python module to convert doc/pdf/docx/rtf formats to text?

Comment: Also for Word: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42482/3377150

Comment: Also for RTF: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1337446/3377150

Answer (score 0):

One module to rule them all!

[textract](http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It supports many file types for text extraction, including all the ones that you specified in your question.

- .doc via antiword
- .pdf via pdftotext (default) or pdfminer.six
- .docx via python-docx
- .rtf via unrtf

**PDF example**

http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_package.html

```
import textract
text = textract.process('path/to/a.pdf', method='pdfminer')
```